# Word for the habit of spending money on things that are not really needed

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there is the word "spendthrift" — but what word denotes the habit of spending too much money or resources on things that are not essential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of these:

- Profligate (n./adj.)
- Squanderer (n)
- Prodigal (n./adj.)
- Waster (n)
- Wasteful (adj)
- Thriftless (adj)

Comment: Annoyingly, [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wastrel%2Cwaster&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that since 1900 use of *[waster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waster)* has become as frequent as that of *[wastrel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wastrel)*.

Answer (score 4):

[frivolous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frivolous) (adj.)

> The frivolous lady would buy anything on a whim
>
> Her frivolity knew no bounds

Answer (score 3):

Besides simply being *wasteful* or *careless* with one's money there is is an expression:

[to fritter away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fritter+away) : to waste something, such as money, on someone or something, foolishly.

> He was known to ***fritter away*** huge sums betting on the horses.

Comment: I was just writing an answer suggesting the same thing. Personally, I sometimes use **fritterer**. Not to describe a truly profligate spendthrift - just someone who's consistently careless about wasting small amounts on non-essentials. Especially if that leads to a situation where they *don't* have the money for something that *is* necessary.

Comment: Really, *[piddler](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piddler)* ("One who [piddles](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piddle)" ie wastes time) seems better to me than does *[fritterer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fritterer)* (one who makes fritters by deep-frying food coated in batter).

Comment: I really don't like it when my dog piddles on the sofa.