# Word for "rich and wasteful"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

We were just thinking that that is a concept that really ought to have a word.  "Wastefully rich"; for example, smoking a $100 bill as a cigarette.

Comment: *Extravagant* suggests unreasonable excess, with an emphasis on wasteful spending (from a usage note under _profuse_, in NOAD)

Comment: Also see [Word for the habit of spending money on things that are not really needed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62952) and (a little less relevant)  [How do you refer to someone who has access to an abundance of resources?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59974), and [ducks and drakes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ducks_and_drakes)

Comment: Aren't they called the 1% ?

Comment: Do you mean that they are so rich that they can be wasteful without effecting their wealth?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are lots of good words that might apply:

- profligate
- extravagant
- spendthrift
- wastrel
- reckless
- cavalier
- squandering
- wasteful

Combining one of these with an immoderate adverb of one sort or another should get the point across just fine.

Comment: Profligate is perfect.

Comment: All of these seem to imply that the money will shortly be gone, however, I get the sense from the OP that they are looking for a term for someone so rich that they can waste money without reducing, or at least without endangering, their wealth.

Answer (score 8):

The word I would normally use in this situation is **[decadent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decadence)**.

It connotes moral decline, deterioration, and importantly, luxurious self-indulgence.

Answer (score 5):

The classic term is ***conspicuous consumption***, coined by Thorstein Veblen in *The Theory of the Leisure Class* (1899).

Comment: Not *quite* the same; *conspicuous consumption* is specifically for show, whereas this can be for other reasons (e.g. it's not worth your time to save money when time is the limiting factor).

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail  Eh?  OP asks specifically for "wasteful" spending.

Answer (score 3):

I like *prodigal* -- especially if the person used to be rich and wasteful but has given it up.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an adjective, I think ***Lavish*** would be perfect. For example:

> A **lavish** cigar.

Comment: *Lavish* doesn't really carry a connotation of wasteful, though (for me).

Comment: @Reid It certainly does. Consider that the verb form of  “lavish” has the following meanings: squander - waste - dissipate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for [**ostentatiously** rich](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deluthered%20thin%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22ostentatiously%20rich%22&oq=%22ostentatiously%20rich%22&gs_l=serp.3...2395299.2401949.13.2402667.21.21.0.0.0.0.129.1389.20j1.21.0...0.0...1c.1.dlMZ2yIu-nk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=46810cf96877f311&biw=1379&bih=886) / [wealthy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deluthered%20thin%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22ostentatiously%20wealthy%22&oq=%22ostentatiously%20wealthy%22&gs_l=serp.3...72977.78188.14.78744.13.13.0.0.0.0.113.967.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.De3ee6fN184&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=46810cf96877f311&biw=1379&bih=886). It's *clear visibility to others* that counts.

Wealthy people don't get or stay that way by habitually "wasting" money. If Bill Gates drinks beer that costs $100 a bottle, that's probably because he *likes* it (and can afford it, obviously).

I'm not sure anyone would prefer smoking a $100 bill rather than a good cigar, but I'd hazard a guess that anyone who actually *did* this would be more concerned with *how the action would be seen by others*, rather than the quality of the experience *per se*.